# Filesearchy alternative - Unable to reach the author or website is not working

Tags: open-source, cross-platform, file-search

FileSearchy is a very excellent free opensource tool where unablet to find any other alternative for this and unable to contact the author or their main web-site doesn't seems to work http://www.filesearchy.com/

Key features:

```
1. Files are indexed
2. search within file contents < less than a second
3. search results are highlighted and easy to navigate the search 
   content files with highlighted text
4. Supports many popular formats - pdf, txt, epub etc.,
5. supports regular expressions
6. copy selected file names, paths, or multiple files to the clipboard, 
   ready for reuse elsewhere
7. The tabbed interface is a notable plus. It’s easy to have multiple 
   searches open and active at the same time.
```

Now it seems pro version is also free (Ref: https://www.portablefreeware.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=21285)

Could someone help me with a similar opensource or free software which has these features ??

Any comments or suggestions would be great.

Link to download:

```
 https://d1ob5g40gc5b6g.cloudfront.net/42/412794/1244134/filesearchy.exe

 http://www.download3k.com/Install-FileSearchy.html
```

I am looking for a cross platform i.e platform independent software, similar to filesearchy.